# pinch-zoom in google map street view mode

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

I am using javascript API for google maps.

I need to have functionality of  pinch-zoom in mobile devices when the map is on street view mode.

I dont see any options for that when i checked in the documentation.

How can i achieve that??